# How to include functions from other C++ files in a new program (for Mac OSX applications)

Tags: c++, macos

How can I import functions from one Mac program I already have into a new program. Both are in the same workspace, but I want too access functions from the older one in the new one. I tried just copying and pasting the functions over (I know, not the greatest way to do it), but got mach-o linker errors that I couldn't fix.

Comment: Could you maybe post your error information or something?

Comment: Without more information we can't possibly help you. What build tool(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is permanent solution.Generally overwriting project may cause this prolems.Try this method.

-UPDATE - Clang error - Mach-O Linker error

In some case error log window displaying .xctest error, to fix it

-> Select your project

-> Beside this(just before General tab) select your projectTest file from dropdown

-> There is one option (like ProjNameTests)

-> In Host Application, select your project from dropdown only if it show custom

DONE!